# batch file move .txt to another folder

Tags: batch-file

i want ot create a batch files but i have not much experience in this.. is anyone can help me?
i want to create a batch file which is the main function is to move some .txt files from a folder (A) to another folder (B)? 
 but those .txt that going move to other file must base by a condition and the condition is when i trigger the batch file i need to know the trigger time or current time and compare the created date and time of .txt file and it must 3 minutes and 3 second ago.. 
 base by this condition i only do the cut and paste from folder A to B 
 is it doable or anyone can provide me a link so i can refer to it.. 
 thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is do able. You need to look at robocopy and it's switches, this should see you right. Just type robocopy /? in cmd and make a note of all the switches you need as there are a lot! There will be other ways of doing this with the if statement but I'm not entirely sure about the timestamp issue. Maybe something like this:

if %Afiletimestamp% < %Bfiletimestamp% xcopy %Afilepath% %Bfilepath% /y

I'm not sure how to aquire the first 2 variables though, maybe someone else can add to this?